# How to Allow Multiple simultaneous VNC sessions?

Tags: 14.04, vnc

I've created an Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine on Amazon Web Services.  This will serve as a development platform for PostgreSQL, Python and Django.  As such, the idea is to have it setup with a bit less restriction than a traditional production server.

We want more than 1 user to VNC into it at a given time.  What must be configured to permit multiple simultaneous VNC connections?

Comment: With each VNC user having it's own session I suppose?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use VNC or would you be willing to use a different protocol supporting the same usecase?

Comment: I've already installed vncserver and don't really want to use a different protocol.  However, if a different protocol is the path of least resistance, I'm all ears :)

Comment: This article explains how you could set it up. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1053242&p=7442474#post7442474 Could you tell us a bit more how this server will be used?